# Socket.io: Updating Chat Room when a new message is added to MongoDB database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, websocket, socket.io

I am creating a real time chat room. However unlike many other examples available, a single chatroom is only accessible to authenticated users, with whom the room is shared with using invitational based authentication.

Here are the steps:

1) Add User on invitation:

```
app.post('/shared', function(req, res){
Room.findOne({_id: req.body._id}. function(err,room){
  new_shared = new Shared({room_id: req.body._id, user_id, req.body.user_id});
  new_shared.save();
  room.shared.push(new_shared);
  room.save();
  res.send(new_shared);
});
});
```

2) Once added to Shared, the user can realtime add messages to only the authenticated users in to room. How can we achieve that?

I am trying this: 
app.post('/message', function(req,res,next){
 // Save Message in Mongodb

//**Emit a socket function - How do we initialize it within API?**

}

3) On Client side, I am using Backbone JS. So once a new message is added, should I call .fetch() method on backbone to retrieve all messages.

I am relatively new to Socket.IO, so some of them might sound stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, `mongodb` and `express` have not great purpose in your chat application, `socket.io` instead carries all the burden.

first you should consider reconstructing the entire approach, you should try the following, for getting a clean result.

- use a simple single route to login users such as `/login` so you can authenticate users using mongodb
- to establish a connection to backend `socket.io`, try to serve the script which handles the connection
- Since you use Backbone, try using a `sync` override, which uses `socket.io` instead of http requests [Backbone.iobind](https://github.com/logicalparadox/backbone.iobind)
- now finally the `socket.io` server which is attached to your expressjs server, should handle the rest

  1. it should authenticate using expressjs sessions
  2. it should handle connections and messages
  3. there is a `.room` functionality built-in `socket.io` so there is no reason in using mongoDB and expressjs.

to sum it up, you could skip expressjs and make use of socket.io, http server, and mongodb *if you store use credentials in database*